# react-native-router-flux back button shows top

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-router-flux

I am trying to create nested routing using react-native-router-flux, but i am getting back button at the top like below (red marked area) :

[image]

My Code :

```
const RouterComponent = () => {
    return(
        <Router>
            <Scene key="root">
                <Scene key="auth">
                    <Scene key="login" component={LoginForm} title="Please Login" />
                </Scene>

                <Scene key="main">
                    <Scene key="userList" component={UserList} title="NUMBER OF DONOR : XX" />
                </Scene>
            </Scene>
        </Router>
    );
};

export default RouterComponent;
```

Platform version : 
react-native : 0.51.0 
react-native-router-flux : 4.0.0-beta.27

Can anybody tell me how can i get back button with title ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got my solution. I solved it by adding `hideNavBar={true}` on parent and `hideNavBar={false}` on child Scene.

```
const RouterComponent = () => {
    return(
        <Router>
            <Scene key="root">
                <Scene key="auth" hideNavBar={true}>
                    <Scene key="login" hideNavBar={false} component={LoginForm} title="Please Login" />
                </Scene>

                <Scene key="main" hideNavBar={true}>
                    <Scene key="userList" hideNavBar={false} component={UserList} title="NUMBER OF DONOR : XX" />
                </Scene>
            </Scene>
        </Router>
    );
};

export default RouterComponent;
```

Answer (score 1):

this is a known issue and I suggest you to have a look at this please :)

https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux/issues/2675

Comment: In my case BackButton shows and works fine but problem is 1st row it shows BackButton and 2nd row it shows Title like my screenshot, they are not showing together.

Answer (score 0):

```
"react-native-router-flux": "4.1.0-beta.2"
```

This works for me.
I set the `back={true}`

```
<Scene key='key' component={MyComponent} title='title' back={true}/>
```